# Session lost with SSL after 1.9.1 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, session, ssl, ce-1.9.1.0, sagepay

Since Magento upgrade 1.9.1 we are getting session lost issues when we have SSL enabled on frontend. This is when going back to magento after payment gateway site.

I understand that the "security" has been improved in this release and I'm wondering what that actually means.

Comment: Where are you saving your sessions to?

Comment: It's not happening on a certain store, several of our customers are experiencing this. Sessions are usually saved in magento files. We are the developers of the payment gateway extension and we started getting this after 1.9.1 upgrade.

Comment: Same issue seems to be occurring here:  https://www.freelancer.com/projects/PHP-Magento/Magento-Multi-Domain-SSL-Session.html

Comment: Are you saving sessions to Files, DB or other? You said "Usually"

Comment: It's the same with files or db

Comment: Martin, did you ever find a workaround. We are dealing with the same problem.

Comment: Colin Mollenhour has released modification for this issue. I think this solved this issue better. https://gist.github.com/colinmollenhour/5066a3220881a9c0c2dd42fa1593cbff/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found the problem:

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

The following code was added:

```
if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure() && empty($cookieParams['secure'])) {
            // secure cookie check to prevent MITM attack
            $secureCookieName = $sessionName . '_cid';
            if (isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])
                && $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] !== md5($cookie->get($secureCookieName))
            ) {
                session_regenerate_id(false);
                $sessionHosts = $this->getSessionHosts();
                $currentCookieDomain = $cookie->getDomain();
                foreach (array_keys($sessionHosts) as $host) {
                    // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
                    if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 0) {
                        $cookie->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
                    }
                }
                $_SESSION = array();
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])) {
                $checkId = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16);
                $cookie->set($secureCookieName, $checkId, null, null, null, true);
                $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] = md5($checkId);
            }
        }
```

I'll try to find a workaround for this...

UPDATE:

We managed a workaround by reloading the saved quote from a GET param on the callback URL, something like this:

```
if($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getId() == null){
                            $rqQuoteId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qid');
                            $this->getOnepage()->setQuote(Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadActive($rqQuoteId));
                            $customer_id = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getData('customer_id');
                            if(!is_null($customer_id)){
                                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
                                if(!is_null($customer)){
                                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Have in mind that this would represent a security risk if anyone can run that URL, make sure it can only be ran once.
If you are saving custom data on the session you'll need to save it on the db, and reload it afterwards. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and located it in this file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

In order to fix it more elegantly one should override the specified file in the "local" code pool insted of modifying the core directly. Like below:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

Also for the above to work php.ini setting `session.cookie_secure` must be commented or set to 0.

Comment: That would work, but I don't advice modifying the core, even if you are creating an override in the local folder. I'd take that as a last resort.